# Keep copied range in Clipboard after range is deselected

Tags: excel, vba, clipboard, copy-paste

I am managing a list of email adresses in Excel that we are using when sending out status reports for a project. It is a list with several hundered rows, and to simplify the maintenance, there is one column containing groupname. There are some email addresses in several places since the person belongs to several groups.

Example: 
John is both in the group "Sales" and "Project group".

When we use the list of email addresses we need to remove duplicates to avoid that the same person get the email several times. So we COPY the whole column with all email addresses, paste it in a new sheet, remove duplicates and then COPY the email adresses again. Now we go to Outlook and PASTE in the To-field and pressing ctrl-k to make Outlook evaluate the adresses. 
After this it is necessary to go back to the excel file and delete that new sheet we created where we deleted duplicates.

I would like to make this automatic, so I created the below script that works well, except that when I delete the temporary sheet (in which I made COPY), the clipboard is emptied. If I comment out the line `ws_dest.Delete` at the end of the code it works.

How can I make the COPY to clipboard in a way that it stays there even after the sheet is deleted? 
Or is there any other solution to my problem?

```
Sub CopyEmailAdresses()
'----------------------------------
'Purpose    To make it simple for the user to grab the list of email adresses
'           without getting any duplicates, so that they can paste the adresses
'           in their email client.
'           Copy the column with email adresses (row 1 is header) and paste in
'           new sheet, remove duplicates and header and copy the row to clipboard.
'           Then delete the temporary sheet.
'------------------------------------
Dim ws_source As Worksheet
Dim ws_dest As Worksheet
    'Remember where we are
    Set ws_source = ActiveSheet
    'Create an empty sheet which will be used for "cleaning" the email adresses
    'and copy the column with amll email adresses
    Set ws_dest = Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
    ws_source.Range("D:D").Copy Destination:=ws_dest.Range("A1")
    'Remove duplicates and the header
    ws_dest.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    ws_dest.Rows("1:1").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    'Copy to clipboard
    ws_dest.Range("A:A").Copy
    'Go back to the source sheet and delete the temporary sheet
    ws_source.Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False    'We dont want the confirmation popup
    ws_dest.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to do a search for "excel outlook vba send e-mail", more than just copying the e-mail addresses can be automated

Comment: Of course! Will check it up.

Comment: @Nybbe a good place to start looking (and what helped me a lot) is Ron De Bruin: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm

Answer (score 2):

Here I add emails to an ArrayList to remove the duplicates, join the list and then add it to the clipboard.

```
Sub CopyEmailAdresses()
    Const EmailDelimiter As String = ";"

    Dim item As Variant, List As Object
    Set List = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each item In .Range("D2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
            If item <> "" And Not List.Contains(item) Then List.Add item
        Next
    End With

    If List.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    With CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        .SetText Join(List.ToArray, EmailDelimiter)
        .PutInClipboard
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Like very much your simple way to solve this problem!

Comment: @Nybbe I forgot to add `List.Contains(item)`.  I made the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks cybernautic.nomad for your idea to look into creating the eamil directly.

Thanks TinMan for showing how to use the ArrayListr and Join. That made my code much simpler.

Here is the code I use now. Still it pretty big, but it works fine.

```
Option Explicit

Function CreateEmail()
' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, Outlook 2010.
' This example sends the last saved version of the Activeworkbook object .
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim emailadr As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim EMAIL_col As Long
Dim HEADER_row As Long
Dim list As Variant
Dim r As Long

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    Set ws = ActiveSheet        'emails are in this sheet
    EMAIL_col = 4               'emails are in this column
    HEADER_row = 1              'Header is on this row
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    r = LastNonEmptyRow(ws.Cells(1, EMAIL_col))
    Do While r > HEADER_row
        emailadr = Trim(ws.Cells(r, EMAIL_col).Value)
        If InStr(emailadr, "@") = 0 Then list.Add emailadr
        r = r - 1
    Loop

    With OutMail
        .To = Join(list.toarray, ";")
        '.CC = "" remove comma and use this if you want to cc anyone, can be string or variable
        '.BCC = "" remove comma and use this if you want to cc anyone, can be string or variable
        .Subject = "DORS"
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY><Font Face=Verdana><p>Email prepared.<br>Click on one of the email adresses and press CTRL_k to tell Outlook to evaluate them.</p></font></BODY></HTML>"
        '.attachments.Remove 1
        '.attachments.Add "C:\Documents and Settings\test.xlsx"
        .Display
       ' .Send
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing


End Function


Function LastNonEmptyRow(rng As Range) As Long
    If rng.Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, rng.Column) <> "" Then
        LastNonEmptyRow = rng.Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, rng.Column).Row
    Else
        LastNonEmptyRow = rng.Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you want to stay away from `.Select` and `.Activate`

Your code should also find the last used row as you are copying the ENTIRE column

To find the last row use: (you can use what ever naming convention you like, In this example I use "LastRow_Unique")

```
LastRow_Unique = ws_source.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Then sub that into a formula to copy/paste the unique valuse all in one line. The change the cell refernce 'D1' and 'A1' as required.

```
ws_source.Range("D1:D" & LastRow_Unique).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ws_dest.Range("A1"), Unique:=True
```

Once you have the unique values copied/paste, you can then re-evaluate the last row and have that range copied else where:

```
LastRow_Unique2 = ws_dest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Thanks for showing how to use the AdvancedFilter to solve this.